# mod_proxy - Alter single path before sending to proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I am using a simple ProxyPass configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /somedir http://proxy.example/somedir
ProxyPassReverse /somedir http://proxy.example/somedir
```

Is it possible to change the root level path before it's sent to the remote proxy, but just that one:

E.g.
http://local.example/somedir would proxy to http://proxy.example/somedir/changed

But
http://local.example/somedir/* would proxy to http://proxy.example/somedir/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<Location /somedir/>
  ProxyPass http://proxy.example/somedir/
  ProxyPassReverse http://proxy.example/somedir/
</Location>

<Location /somedir>
  ProxyPass http://proxy.example/somedir/changed
  ProxyPassReverse http://proxy.example/somedir/changed
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - this works, except if you type http://local.example/somedir/ (ending slash), is there anyway to prevent that? Looks like you can do it with RegEx, just trying to figure out syntax.